# Why Firebase Push Notification does not working when I install the real program. Swift3

Tags: firebase, push-notification, swift3

Firebase push notification is running when I install it from the my development computer where I prepare the software. But firebase notification does not work when I install from the "App Store" on my phone.

My Xcode output like this.

2017-01-26 11:04:50.257 AydinDagV1[1699:251861] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-01-26 11:04:50.345 AydinDagV1[1699]  [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2017-01-26 11:04:50.366 AydinDagV1[1699:]  Firebase Analytics v.3501000 started
2017-01-26 11:04:50.367 AydinDagV1[1699:]  To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see -ttp://googl/Y0Yjwu)
2017-01-26 11:04:50.377:  FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-01-26 11:04:50.378:  Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2017-01-26 11:04:50.381:  FIRMessaging library version 1.2.0
2017-01-26 11:04:50.397:  FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-01-26 11:04:50.413 AydinDagV1[1699:]  Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-01-26 11:04:50.490:  Cannot subscribe to topic: /topics/news with token: (null)
Notification was granted
2017-01-26 11:04:50.606:  Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
2017-01-26 11:04:50.703 AydinDagV1[1699:]  The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at -ttp://googl/9vSsPb
2017-01-26 11:04:50.717 AydinDagV1[1699:]  Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-01-26 11:04:50.856 AydinDagV1[1699]  [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
Succecfull Connecting
Notification was granted

Answer (score 0):

Add a production APNS certificate to your Firebase application in the console under project settings > cloud messaging.

If that doesn't solve the problem, check that your APNS environment is production. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40906618/6280950

Comment: I solved the problem. It was Certification problem. for example if you want to send notification message from the firebase need to upload production certificate file. But first important issue production .p12 file It must be unencrypted. I uploaded to new .p12 file and notification services working..